# Integral to partial sum

Tags: integration, summation

This is an addition on a question I asked earlier. I was given the following functions:
$$g(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^{4/3}}\ln(1+\ln x)$$ $$f(x)=g(2x-1)-g(2x)$$

"I" (with help) showed that:

$$2\int_{a}^\infty f(x)dx =\int_{2a-1}^{2a}g(x)dx$$

Now the question is whether it is possible to show that$$S_N=\sum_{k=1}^{2N}(-1)^{k-1}g(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{N}f(k)$$
I understand that we are going from an integral to a partial sum. And I "feel" that the solution is in the $2N$, Any help and hints welcome, Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the sum in two by summing separately odd indices and even indices:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2N}(-1)^{k-1}g(k)=\sum_{j=1}^{N}g(2j-1)
-\sum_{j=1}^{N}g(2j)=
\sum_{j=1}^{N}(g(2j-1)-g(2j))=\sum_{j=1}^{N}f(j).$$